# Driving 7-segment displays

Tags: c++, embedded, arduino, device-driver

I made a little JavaScript app [here](http://blog.vitim.us/2014/11/character-generator-for-7-segments.html) that let people generate bitmap for generating characters. Currently it generate code of a dictionary. But I want to also generate a example that let them play like the Arduino samples, use it as starting point or use it as-is.

This is the code I wrote to enable someone to use 7-segment displays

I want some feedback on the code itself also things like suggestions for variable and function names, order of things, aesthetics etc...

```
//common cathode turns on with HIGH, and common anode turns on with LOW
const bool LED_P HIGH

const uint8_t myDisplayPins[8] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; //dp A B C D E F G

byte font[] = {
    B1111110,   // [0] => "0"
    B0110000,   // [1] => "1"
    B1101101,   // [2] => "2"
    B1111001,   // [3] => "3"
    B0110011,   // [4] => "4"
    B1011011,   // [5] => "5"
    B1011111,   // [6] => "6"
    B1110000,   // [7] => "7"
    B1111111,   // [8] => "8"
    B1111011,   // [9] => "9"
    B1110111,   // [10] => "A"
    B0000001,   // [11] => "dash"
};

void setup(){
    display7Setup(myDisplayPins); //configure myDisplayPins as outputs
}

void loop(){

  display7(myDisplayPins, font[0]); //display "0"
  delay(1000);
  display7(myDisplayPins, font[9]); //display "A"
  delay(1000);
  display7(myDisplayPins, font[11]); //display "-"
  delay(1000);
  display7(myDisplayPins, B00000000); //turn all segments OFF
  delay(1000);

  //count 0 to 9
  for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){
    display7(myDisplayPins, font[i]);
    delay(1000);
  }

}


/* Configure pins as outputs */
void display7Setup(const uint8_t displayPins[]){
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<8; ++i){
    pinMode(displayPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

/* Function that writes a bitmap to a 7-segment display */
void display7(const uint8_t displayPins[], byte bitmap){
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<8; ++i){
    byte segment = bitmap & (0x1<<i); //apply a mask to select just the desired segment bit
    bool state = segment>>i;          //shift the bit to LSF (rightmost) to get a boolean value 0x1 or 0x0
    if(!LEDP) state = !state;         //invert level for common anode
    digitalWrite(displayPins[i], state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- I would rename `loop` to `demo`.
- The spec says that the `value` argument to `digitalWrite` may only be `HIGH` or `LOW`, and it doesn't spell out their bit representations. Even though your code works (I presume), it is better to stick with the spec.
- `LEDP` never changes. You don't have to invert each individual bit in the loop. It looks better to invert the whole bitmap at once:

  ```
  if (LEDP == LOW) {
      bitmap ^= 0xff;
  }
  ```
- Now the body of `display7` loop could be streamlined to

  ```
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<8; ++i) {
      digitalWrite(displayPins[i], (bitmap & 0x01)? HIGH: LOW);
      bitmap >>= 1;
  }
  ```

  Notice that `segment` and `state` disappear altogether.

Comment: on the arduino.h high/low is the same as true and false `#define HIGH 0x1 #define LOW 0x0`. But I like to keep it semantic. but why not use `~` ?